# SQL Query Returning only 5 records instead of 6 rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, connect-by

I am trying to fetch the data present in a single column which is delimited with double hash (##). As per my query mentioned below, i am able to fetch only 5 records instead of 6 lines.

I could think there is some issue with my `connectby` expression. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Data**

```
Line1## Line2## Line3 ## Line4 ## Line5  ## Line6  ##
```

Query Used to fetch the records in a single record which are delimited with double hash ##

Replicate the scenario:

```
create table temp (errormessage varchar2(300))

insert into  temp errormessage values('Line1## Line2## Line3 ## Line4 ## Line5  ## Line6  ##')



WITH sample_data
     AS ( SELECT errormessage AS Error_Message
          FROM   TEMP )
SELECT Regexp_substr( error_message, ',?([^#]*)', 1, LEVEL, 'i', 1 ) AS Error_Message
FROM   sample_data
WHERE  Length( Regexp_substr( error_message, ',?([^#]*)', 1, LEVEL, 'i', 1 ) ) != 0
CONNECT BY ( Regexp_count(error_message, '#') + 1 >= LEVEL AND
             PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL )
ORDER  BY LEVEL
```

Error Message is the column which has the info to be delimited. Now it is pretty easy to replicate the issue in any of your databases.

Comment: Can you post enough info to replicate the issue - e.g. create table SQL for table TEMP and the 6 insert statements to set up the data?

Comment: Sure, let me try creating that

Comment: @TonyAndrews Now you should be able to replicate the scenario easily.

Comment: I can - but I'm afraid I can't understand what the query is doing, so unable to help!

Comment: I was able to resolve it after updating the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're after something like:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 stagging_id,
                            'A' status,
                            'Line1## Line2## Line3 ## Line4 ## Line5  ## Line6  ##' error_message
                     FROM   dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 stagging_id,
                            'B' status,
                            'Line1## Line2## Line3 ## Line4 ## Line5  ## Line6  ##Line7  ##' error_message
                     FROM   dual)
SELECT stagging_id,
       status,
       regexp_substr(error_message, '[^#]+', 1, LEVEL) err_msg
FROM   sample_data
CONNECT BY PRIOR stagging_id = stagging_id
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
           AND regexp_substr(error_message, '[^#]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

STAGGING_ID STATUS ERR_MSG
----------- ------ --------------------------------------------------------------
          1 A      Line1
          1 A       Line2
          1 A       Line3
          1 A       Line4
          1 A       Line5
          1 A       Line6
          2 B      Line1
          2 B       Line2
          2 B       Line3
          2 B       Line4
          2 B       Line5
          2 B       Line6
          2 B      Line7
```

The issue with your existing code is the `*` in the regexp_substr, plus the fact that you're counting single `#` whereas your delimiter is `##`.

You could fix your query like so:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 stagging_id,
                            'A' status,
                            'Line1## Line2## Line3 ## Line4 ## Line5  ## Line6  ##' error_message
                     FROM   dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 stagging_id,
                            'B' status,
                            'Line1## Line2## Line3 ## Line4 ## Line5  ## Line6  ##Line7  ##' error_message
                     FROM   dual)
SELECT Regexp_substr( error_message, ',?([^#]+)', 1, LEVEL, 'i', 1 ) AS Error_Message
FROM   sample_dataCONNECT BY ( Regexp_count(error_message, '##') >= LEVEL AND
             PRIOR stagging_id = stagging_id AND
             PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL )
ORDER  BY stagging_id, LEVEL;

ERROR_MESSAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------
Line1
 Line2
 Line3
 Line4
 Line5
 Line6
Line1
 Line2
 Line3
 Line4
 Line5
 Line6
Line7
```

Note how I've changed the `*`s to `+`s in the regexp_substr's and the `'#'` to `'##'` in the regexp_count.

Comment: I am looking for something like this:   Line1
 Line2
 Line3 
 Line4 
 Line5   Line6

Comment: Could you please try using the latest query as i have updated the code for easy replication.!

Comment: You're looking for the line1, line2, etc on different rows? if so, how does my answer not give you what you're after?

Comment: i am afraid of the timing it is taking to run the query. Usual time is around few seconds. This query is being run for 2 mins atleast

Comment: Updating your regex or mine? Hopefully you also spotted that in the fixed version of your original query, you no longer need the where clause to filter out the rows you were over-generating due to the inefficient regexp_count in the connect by clause?

Comment: You are correct. I observed the efficiency in run time as well after doing that.